# Loading XML into MySQL with duplicate tags

Tags: mysql, xml

I need to load this XML into a MySQL Database. The problem is - within the "matchup" section, there are two repeating sequences and I need to get them into the same row of the Table. Specifically, I need load "team_key" into my table as two different columns: "team_key_1" & "team_key_2".  Any thoughts on how I can do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fantasy_content xml:lang="en-US" yahoo:uri="http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/league/123.l.12345/scoreboard;week=1" time="123.44789505005ms" copyright="Data provided by Yahoo! and STATS, LLC" refresh_rate="31" xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" xmlns="http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/base.rng">
 <league>
  <league_key>123.l.12345</league_key>
  <scoreboard>
   <week>1</week>
   <matchups count="1">
    <matchup>
     <week>1</week>
     <week_start>2015-04-05</week_start>
     <week_end>2015-04-12</week_end>
     <teams count="2">
      <team>
       <team_key>123.l.12345.t.1</team_key>
      </team>
      <team>
       <team_key>123.l.12345.t.2</team_key>
      </team>
     </teams>
    </matchup>
   </matchups>
  </scoreboard>
 </league>
</fantasy_content>
```

I'm using the following query today:

```
load xml infile "d:/data.xml" into table teams rows identified by <matchup>
```

In this case, if I define the columns as "team_key_1" & "team_key_2", then both are null.

If I define one column as "team_key", then only column gets populated.

I'm struggling getting both columns populated.

Ideally, the table would look like:

```
league_key  | week |    team_key_1   |    team_key_2  |
------------------------------------------------------
123.l.12345 |  1   | 123.l.12345.t.1 | 123.l.12345.t.2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the cleanest solution, but the easiest:
You can load the XML changing "rows identified by matchup" for "rows identified by team", and load all in a temporary table.
Second step: update the non-temporary table with the pair values (you just have to fill it using a select * from temp where mod(id,2)=0 )
Third step: fill the odd values: select * from temp where mod(id,2)=1